# How to implement custom icon font with CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I'm wondering how to implement these icons using CSS.

Here is the CSS:

```
.icon {
    font-family: 'spokeo';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    position: relative;
}

.search_icon:before         { content:'\e001'; }
.down_arrow_icon:before     { content:'\e002'; }
.up_arrow_icon:before       { content:'\e003'; }

...etc
```

And the HTML:

```
<div>
    <i class="toc_icon"></i>Table of Contents
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the question here? Have you tried using the CSS listed? What happened, and what were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: I should have included that instead of icons appearing, I'm seeing placeholder squares... Wondering if it could be a permissions issue with the font I'm using.

Comment: @Ali Torbati Have you tried changing your charset to UTF-8? Edit your question and add all the markup and CSS you're using so I can replicate it on my machine and possibly find a solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you will need to do is import the font using @font-face in the CSS.

You will need the four major filetypes for the icons to have cross-browser functionality. These are `eot` `ttf` `svg` and `woff`. A good free resource for icon font sets is [fontello.com](http://fontello.com/):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'spokeo';
    src: url('path/to/spokeo.eot');
    src: url('path/to/spokeo.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('path/to/spokeo.woff') format('woff'),
         url('path/to/spokeo.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('path/to/spokeo.svg#spokeo') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The above imports the font to the browser for use later when you call the icons in your page.

You will now define the .icon class in the stylesheet like you did in your example:

```
.icon {
    font-family: 'spokeo';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    position: relative;
}

.search_icon:before         { content:'\e001'; }
.down_arrow_icon:before     { content:'\e002'; }
.up_arrow_icon:before       { content:'\e003'; }
```

And then in your HTML you would write in the `icon` class as well as the specific class in your icon so that it includes all of the styles associated with all icons and then the specific icon contents, like this:

```
<div>
    <i class="icon search_icon"></i>Search
    <i class="icon down_arrow_icon"></i>Down
    etc...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

full code with working demo

[`jfFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/dWcFy/)

### html

```
<div>
    <i class="icon search_icon"></i> Search
</div>

<div>
    <i class="icon down_arrow_icon"></i> Down Arrow
</div>

<div>
    <i class="icon up_arrow_icon"></i> Up Arrow
</div>
```

### css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'spokeo';
    src: url('http://getbootstrap.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('http://getbootstrap.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),  
        url('http://getbootstrap.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'),  
        url('http://getbootstrap.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'),  
        url('http://getbootstrap.com/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.icon {
    font-family: 'spokeo';
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    position: relative;
}
.search_icon:before {
    content: '\e003';
}
.down_arrow_icon:before {
    content: '\e094';
}
.up_arrow_icon:before {
    content: '\e093';
}
```